# Filtering After a Specific Date Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to filter after a specific date in spark I have the following RDD, I have an array of 2 strings the first is a Date and next is a Path, I want to check what Path's have changed after a specific date:

```
val cleanRDD = oivRDD.map(x => (x(5), x(7)))
```

> res16: Array[(String, String)] =
>   Array(
>   (2015-06-24,/), (2015-07-17,/cdh), (2015-06-26,/datameer),
>   (2015-06-24,/devl), (2015-08-11,/dqa), (2015-03-12,/lake),
>   (2015-02-13,/osa))

I'm Using Java's SimpleDateFormt:

```
val sampleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val filterRDD = cleanRDD.filter(x => dateCompare(x))
```

My Date Compare:

```
  def dateCompare(input:(String, String)): Boolean = {
    val date1 = sampleDate.format(input._1)
    val date2 = sampleDate.parse(date1)
    val date3 = sampleDate.parse("2015-07-01")
    if (date2.compareTo(date3) > 0)  true
    else
      false
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

> 15/08/12 10:21:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID
>   10, edhpdn2128.kdc.capitalone.com):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date

Comment: You are trying to format a string: `sampleDate.format(input._1)`

Comment: Removing this line should make it work.

Comment: Oh wow simple error that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

With the new dataframe framework, it's valid an expression like:

```
dfLogging.filter(dfLogging("when") >= "2015-01-01")
```

The column has **timestamp** type:

```
scala> dfLogging.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- when: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- ...
```

This syntax is valid for Scala, but should be similar for Java and Pyhton